# Application of Dirichlet integral

Tags: real-analysis

> evaluate $$\frac{\sin1+2\sin\frac12+3\sin\frac13+\dots+n\sin\frac1n}{n}$$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

I think

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1)}{1} + \frac{\sin\left(\frac12\right)}{2} + \dots + \frac{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}{n}$$

This is known as the Dirichlet integral, and it is well-known to be convergent. Therefore, the limit exists and is finite. However, the exact value of the limit cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Here the Dirichlet integral is defined as $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-s} \sin x dx$ where $s$ is complex number with real part $>1$

Am i right... actually I didn't find this question in mathstackexchange earlier...
Please solve this or give any hints... thank you

Comment: Check your definition of Dirichlet integral please, as far as I remind, the Dirichlet integral is defined as $\int_{0 \to 1} (x^s - 1)sin(\pi x) dx$ for a complex number $s$ with a real part $> 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_{n}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$ exists then $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_{k}}{N}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$

Take $x_{n}=n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ . Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$

Thus $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N}x_{k}}{N}=1$

Here's a proof of the result I used,

See that if $x_{n}\to a  $  then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{1}$ such that $|x_{n}-a|\leq \epsilon\,,\forall \,n\geq N_{1}$ . Then for $M>N_{1}$ you have $$|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|=|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}x_{k}}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|$$

$$=|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}(x_{k}-a)}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}(x_{k}-a)}{M}|$$

Now pick $M_{1}>N_{1}$ such that $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}|x_{k}-a|<\epsilon$ for all $m\geq M_{1}$ . Notice that $M_{1}$ depends on $N_{1}$ and $\epsilon$ and hence only on $\epsilon$ as $N_{1}$ depends only on $\epsilon$ .

Now $|x_{k}-a|\leq \epsilon \,,\forall n\geq N_{1}$ . Hence $\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}\frac{|x_{k}-a|}{M}\leq \frac{\epsilon (M-N_{1}+1)}{M}\leq \epsilon$

Thus for all $M\geq M_{1}$ you have $|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{M}x_{k}}{M}-a|\leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{N_{1}-1}|x_{k}-a|}{M}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{1}}^{M}|x_{k}-a|}{M}\leq \epsilon+\epsilon$

Hence you have the required convergence

**This is what is called Cauchy's First Limit Theorem in some books.** Intuitively what it means is that the arithmetic mean of the sequence also converges to the same limit as the sequence. In addition if $x_n>0$ you can take log and show that the Geometric mean also convetges to the same limit as the original sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$S_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k\sin \frac{1}{k}.
$$

First, using $\sin u \le u$ for all $u \ge 0$, we have
$$S_n \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = 1.
$$

Second, using $\sin u \ge u - u^3/6$ for all $u\ge 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 S_n
 &\ge \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{6k^3}\right)\\
 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{1}{6k^2}\right)\\
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{6n}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k^2}\\
 &\ge 1 - \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{6n}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{(k-1)k}\\
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{6n}\sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\right)\\
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{6n^2}.
\end{align*}

Thus, we have
$$1 - \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{6n^2} \le S_n \le 1.$$

By the squeeze theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = 1.$$